# onClick запись значения ссылки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как сделать чтобы при выборе кода, через  onclick прокидывалось значение в функцию и записывалось значение в переменную

```js
let code = '';
function changeCodeValue(code){

}
$(".menu-item").click(function() {
  $(".menu-item a")
    .parent()
    .removeClass("active-picker");
  $(this).addClass("active-picker");
});
```

```html
<div class="menu-picker gray-400">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center ">
        <p class="menu-title">Code1</p>
        <div class="w-100">
          <ul class="d-flex justify-content-center" onclick="changeCodeValue()">
            <li class="menu-item code active-picker">
              <a href="#">JEDMXP</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item code">
              <a href="#">JFKMXP</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item code">
              <a href="#">JFKPRG</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: если верно вам понимаю, то внутри функции просто добавить code =  $(this).find(a).text();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(".menu-item").click(function() {
      $(".menu-item").removeClass("active-picker");
      $(this).addClass("active-picker");
      let code = $(this).children().html();
      changeCodeValue(code);
  });
```

`onclick="changeCodeValue()"` можно убрать